# .net socket problem: client disconnect from server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

On server side I have this code which running in new thread

```
static void ListenForConsultant()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2111);
            serverSocket.Start();
            var clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            consultantConnected = true;
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Consultant Connected");
            byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
            while (true)
            {
                if (!clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                    break;
                }
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                var dataFromConsultant = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                if (dataFromConsultant.IndexOf("~") != -1 && dataFromConsultant.IndexOf("^") != -1 && dataFromConsultant.IndexOf("^") > dataFromConsultant.IndexOf("~"))
                {
                    var lengthOfMessage = dataFromConsultant.IndexOf("^") - dataFromConsultant.IndexOf("~") - 1;
                    dataFromConsultant = dataFromConsultant.Substring(dataFromConsultant.IndexOf("~") + 1, lengthOfMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine(" >> From consultant:" + dataFromConsultant);
                }

            }

            consultantConnected = false;
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Consultant Disconnected");

            serverSocket.Stop();
        }
    }
```

I connect using putty to port 2111. All works ok, but when I close putty socket doesn't close, however I have condition

```
if (!clientSocket.Connected)
{
      break;
}
```

Debug shows me that clientSocket.Connected is true even after I disconnected from server.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tcpClient.Connected` property value is not reliable, it's value depending on the last communication; so if the last communication were succeed then it's value is true otherwise it is false. for more information on that check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected.aspx).

Use this IsConnected property to check if the tcpClient is connected:

```
public static bool IsConnected
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            //return _tcpClient != null && _tcpClient.Client != null && _tcpClient.Client.Connected;

            if (_tcpClient != null && _tcpClient.Client != null && _tcpClient.Client.Connected)
            {

                /* As the documentation:
                    * When passing SelectMode.SelectRead as a parameter to the Poll method it will return 
                    * -either- true if Socket.Listen(Int32) has been called and a connection is pending;
                    * -or- true if data is available for reading; 
                    * -or- true if the connection has been closed, reset, or terminated; 
                    * otherwise, returns false
                    */

                // Detect if client disconnected
                if (_tcpClient.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                {
                    byte[] buff = new byte[1];
                    if (_tcpClient.Client.Receive(buff, SocketFlags.Peek) == 0)
                    {
                        // Client disconnected
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Note that checking `IsConnected` will not prevents it from disconnect after the check. i.e  its possible to happen that the socket is disconnected just after it was connected "after the `IsConnected` check evaluated and return true", So you should wrap all communication in `try/catch` or `try/catch/finally` block expecting the socket to be disconnected at any time.

Comment: what should I use instead of this property for determining state of client?

Comment: updated the answer: code [from my previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452992/tcpclient-disconnect-during-async-read/6455369#6455369).